# I want to upload file to my server from localhost in php

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, server

is this possible to upload file to online server from my localhost?

My code is here

```
<?php

if ( !empty( $_FILES ) ) 
{
    $tempPath = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
    $uploadPath = "http://xyz.biz/avatar/demo1.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $tempPath, $uploadPath );
    $answer = array( 'answer' => 'File transfer completed' );
    $json = json_encode( $answer );
    echo $json;

}
else 
{
    echo 'No files';
}

?>
```

I am not able to upload file on my server.

Can you please assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's irrelevant where your server is hosted as long as you can connect it through any firewall eventually standing in-between. Further: what means "able to upload"? You can `scp` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean upload file from localhost to online server using PHP?

Firstly, create a php file on server (forexample: http://xyz.biz/upload.php) with following content

```
<?php
$files = @$_FILES["files"];
if($files["name"] != '')
{
    $fullpath = $_REQUEST["path"].$files["name"];
    if(move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'],$fullpath))
    {           
        echo "<h1><a href='$fullpath'>OK-Click here!</a></h1>";     
    }
}
echo '<html><head><title>Upload files...</title></head><body><form method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""><input type=text name=path><input type="file" name="files"><input type=submit value="Up">
</form></body></html>';

?>
```

Then, goto url: http://xyz.biz/upload.php and select file and relative path to upload

Comment: Thanks for this code but I want to do it by locally. Is there any way?

Comment: You must have at least a php file on the server to handle the request (eg, receive file) from localhost. Then in localhost, you can use phpcurl to post file to the request handle